# How to disable history in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, history

I've googled this and read other similar questions, all sources say that it's needed to disable Web & App activity in google account settings.

I did it, but when i visit any page after this and refresh history page, history still gets a new record. Has Google restricted such possibility?

Comment: https://www.techjunkie.com/prevent-google-chrome-storing-browser-history/